# S3 directory listing without extraneous fields

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm using `GET /?list-type=2` to get a directory listing from an S3 bucket.  This returns an XML document with a `Contents` element for each bucket item.  This element contains a lot of extra fields that I'm not using, such as `LastModified`, `ETag`, `Size`, `StorageClass` and `Owner`.

Is there any way to request that only the `Key` field be included, for each bucket item?

I'd like to keep the size of this directory listing as small as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official source would be the [AWS manual page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/v2-RESTBucketGET.html), which doesn't document any means to modify fields included in the response (except to include or omit the owner information.)